# How do I "freeze" the variable in place? (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

Don't really know if I asked the question correct, since I don't really know what causes it here but let me show.

```py
                unscrambled = random.choice(wordshack)
                scrambled = scramble(unscrambled)
                twork = await ctx.send(f"You have 120 seconds and 1 try to unscramble: {scrambled}")

                try:
                    msg = await self.client.wait_for(
                    "message",
                    timeout=120,
                    check= lambda message: message.author == ctx.author
                    and message.channel == ctx.channel
                    )
                    if msg == unscrambled:
                        await ctx.send(f"You worked as hacker and earned {hack}$")
```

Read the last two lines, the msg == unscrambled just doesn't function at all, I probably know why, but I don't know how to solve this so my bot works fast enough

Comment: Does it work if you replace it with `msg.content`?

Comment: @duckboycool it does! thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

User duckboycool helped me with this. Just replace msg -> msg.content and it will work!